# Using EditText in Activity Group

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, activitygroup

In my application i am using tabhost. And to control different activities i am using activity group. I have Activity A from which i am going to activity B. Activity B contains Edit Text, Spinner, Button etc. Now when i scroll the Activity B and press the device Back Button than it does not go to the previous Activity. It goes out of application.
Kindly suggest the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the Activity lifecycle works for Activity Group. Try using fragments instead of activity group with your tabhost to get your movements. Also, please edit your question title to more accurately reflect the actual question.